# A simple depreciation problem

Tags: arithmetic

Question 2: The share price of a public company fell 4% on each day of a week, from Monday to Friday. What is the price of a share at the end of the trading day on Friday, if the share was valued at $20 on the Sunday of the same week?

I could do this the long way by calculating the depreciation for each day as:
monday: 20 -4% of 20
tuesday:monday-4% of monday
wed: tuesday-4% of tuesday
and so on to friday

This method takes a lot of time. What is the shortest way of finding the answer? could depreciation formula could be used for it?

Comment: rate falls only from monday to friday

Comment: Weekends - No rise, no fall, just steady?

Comment: I thought weeks started on Mondays!

Comment: ans is (1 - .04)^5·$20

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closing price on Friday is $20(0.96)^5$.

Similarly, if the price **increases** by say $6\%$ each day, then in $5$ days it gets multiplied by $(1.06)^5$.

Answer (score 1):

Sunday - price = $20$

Monday - $20 \times 0.96$

Tuesday - $20 \times 0.96^2$

Wednesday - $20 \times 0.96^3$

Thursday - $20 \times 0.96^4$

Friday - no weekend days to consider - price = $20 \times (0.96)^5$